# Ошибка call to a member function query() on a non-object in php mysqli

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

выскакивает ошибка  call to a member function query() on a non-object

```
$resut = $mysqli->query("SELECT users FROM $gid WHERE $gid.id != 1 ");
$myro = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resut);
function insertLogin($myro)
{
    while ($myro == true) {
        $myroq = $myro['users'];
        $result = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE users.login='$myroq'");
        $myros = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
        $orgroupcountnew = $myros['orgoup'] + 1;
        $gncountnew = $myros['gn'] + 1;
        $rest = $mysqli->query("UPDATE users SET balance ='$balance', gn = '$gncountnew', orgroup = '$orgroupcountnew' WHERE users.login= '$myroq'");
    }
}
```

Переменная `$mysqli` объявлена в самом начале документа

```
$mysqli = new mysqli ("127.0.0.1:3306", "root", "", "mybase");
$mysqli->query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
```

и при вызове этой функции  `insertLogin ($myro);`
выдает, что ошибка в этой строчке

```
$rest = $mysqli ->query("UPDATE `users` SET `balance` ='$balance', `gn` = '$gncountnew', `orgroup` = '$orgroupcountnew' WHERE `users`.`login` = '$myroq'");
```

хотя до этого вызывается почти аналогичный запрос, но чуть другим методом (причем, если переписать  `$result = mysqli_query` на `$mysqli ->query`, будет выдавать ошибку и в этой строчке, но если переделать `$rest = $mysqli ->query`  на     `mysqli_query` ничего работать не будет вообще, страница зависает при перезагрузке и все.

Читал, что нужно сделать через глобальную переменную и тд, но не получается ибо вставляю `global $mysqli` в функцию, страница опять виснет. Проблема еще в том, что это не весь код и закрывать и переоткрывать подключение не получается, не работает остальное. Помогите и объясните, пожалуйста, что нужно сделать

Попытался чуть по- другому

```
function insertLogin ($resut) {
    while (($myroq = $resut-> fetch_assoc()) != false) {
        $myroq = $resut['users'];
```

и

```
$resut = $mysqli->query("SELECT `users` FROM `$gid` WHERE `$gid`.`id` != 1 " ); 
insertLogin ($resut);
```

но все равно выскакивает ошибка

Comment: все верно, внутри функции `insertLogin` не существует переменной `$mysqli`, она в другой области видимости: просто передайте ее в функцию как второй параметр (как пример)

Comment: Можете поподробней объяснить как это сделать, ибо я начинающий и еще не добрался до этого (не встречал подобных ситуаций), спасибо.

Comment: Описал, надеюсь поможет. Однако, если я не ошибаюсь, то переменная `$balance`, внутри функции у вас тоже не определена

Comment: я написал код по вашему прошлому комментарию в ответы , посмотрите, пожалуйста

Answer (score 1):

Добавьте второй параметр в параметры функции

```
$resut = $mysqli->query("SELECT users FROM $gid WHERE $gid.id != 1 ");
$myro = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resut);
function insertLogin($myro, $mysqli)
{
    while ($myro == true) {
        $myroq = $myro['users'];
        $result = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE users.login='$myroq'");
        $myros = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
        $orgroupcountnew = $myros['orgoup'] + 1;
        $gncountnew = $myros['gn'] + 1;
        $rest = $mysqli->query("UPDATE users SET balance ='$balance', gn = '$gncountnew', orgroup = '$orgroupcountnew' WHERE users.login= '$myroq'");
    }
}
```

Выделю место которое изменилось `function insertLogin($myro, $mysqli)`

Comment: к сожалению, виснет (не работает). Баланс я забыл убрать случайно

Comment: Ну хоть какая-то ошибка есть?

Comment: не, просто ничего не происходит, пытаюсь перезагрузить страницу  и она не перзагружается, останавливаю и получаю ответ от аджакс, что скрипт не найден (это я выставлял в нем в случае ошибки)

Comment: еще вопрос при вызове функции мы также указываем `insertLogin($myro, $mysqli)` или без $mysqli?

Comment: Конечно `$mysqli` необходимо указывать в параметрах. так как эта переменная, в области видимости функции отсутствует, следовательно ее надо передать. Но без ошибки или какого-то лога ошибок, я помочь не смогу, просто виснет - ни о чем не говорит.

Comment: а как можно сделать по-другому? Есть две таблицы в одной содержится вся информация о пользователях `users`, а вторая таблица это как группа (обозначим как group), и при определенном событии берутся все логины из group, затем  выбираются данные к примеру `y` и `o` из `users` о этих логинах, к содержащемуся в них значению прибавляется + 1  и в них же вставляется это значение. Но загвоздка для меня именно в том, как сделать это для каждого логина из таблицы group

Comment: Я бы в вашем случае делал выборку из group, далее сделал бы обновление `UPDATE users SET chtoto = chtoto + 1 where in (userIds)` и получается, цикл уже не нужны, вы обновите необходимые записи за один раз

Comment: задал новый вопрос, посмотрите, пожалуйста https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/909757/311038