# Как правильно написать код php & mysqli

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

задача такая : Есть две таблицы в одной содержится вся информация о пользователях users, а вторая таблица это как группа (обозначим как group), и при определенном событии берутся все логины из group, затем выбираются данные к примеру y и o из users о этих логинах, к содержащемуся в них значению прибавляется + 1 и в них же вставляется это значение. Но загвоздка для меня именно в том, как сделать это для каждого логина из таблицы group.
Пробовал одним способом ([Ошибка call to a member function query() on a non-object in php mysqli](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/909683/311038)) - не получилось. В комментариях посоветовали "Я бы в вашем случае делал выборку из group, далее сделал бы обновление UPDATE users SET chtoto = chtoto + 1 where in (userIds) и получается, цикл уже не нужны, вы обновите необходимые записи за один раз".
Я попробовал написать такой код

```
$resut = $mysqli->query("SELECT `users` FROM `$gid` WHERE `$gid`.`id` != 1 ");
$myro = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resut);
$rest = $mysqli->query("UPDATE `users` SET  `gn` = `gn` + 1, `orgroup` = `orgroup` + 1 WHERE `users`.`login` = '$myro'");
```

Но он что-то не особо работает, как это исправить или вообще переписать код, благодарю.

Comment: Убиццо... То есть задача - тупо для определённой группы (или определённого набора групп) инкрементировать значение какого-то поля, что ли? если да - это один несложный запрос. *В комментариях посоветовали* Пэхапэшник советовал... не слушай.

Comment: да, в базе формируются таблицы (там записаны логины юзеров,как они попадают туда это уже другая история и к этому отношения не имеет), она представляет собой группу людей с их логинами и от этого пляшем. А можно поконкретней про запрос, как его составить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sql
UPDATE users u, groups g
SET u.gn = u.gn + 1
WHERE u.login = g.users -- связь таблиц
  AND g.id = @id        -- группа, которая обновляется
```

Comment: в итоге мой запрос должен выглядеть так, если обозначение (путь к) groups находиться в переменной $gid и еще там маленькое условие нужно, что выбирать users из group нужно только с цифры 2 (то есть >1). `$rest = $mysqli->query("UPDATE users u, $gid g SET u.gn = u.gn + 1 WHERE u.login = g.users AND g.id = @id");`     И  я чуток не понял  `AND g.id = @id        -- группа, которая обновляется` можете объяснить, пожалуйста?

Comment: Я не понял... у Вас что, для каждой группы отдельная таблица, что ли???

Comment: Да, спасибо большое, я чуть подкорректировал ваш ответ и все заработало, благодарю еще раз, убил на это полдня